# FullCalendar React - Setting Monday as the first day of the week

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using FullCalendar with React, and I'm trying to set Monday as the first day of the week specifically for the timeGridWeek view. I have tried using the firstDay option, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here's my current code for setting up the timeGridWeek view:

```
timeGridWeek: { buttonText: 'Week', firstDay: 1 },
```

Despite specifying firstDay: 1, the calendar still starts with Sunday.

I expected the timeGridWeek view to start with Monday as the first day of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`firstDay`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/firstDay) isn't an option which can be applied specifically to a single view. You must specify it globally:

```
views: {
  timeGridWeek: { buttonText: 'Week' }
},
firstDay: 1
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYXWMLx

If you want to request an enhancement to enable that, see fullCalendar's [Requesting Features](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) guide.